# Dropdown populated by AJAX not getting initial vlaue set

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page with a table with a button to add rows dynamically and a way to remove rows as well.  On each row there are 2 drop down lists that are cascading.  When a row is created I use an AJAX call to populate the first dropdown with values.  On the change event of this dropdown I do another AJAX call to populate the second dropdown.  This all works fine but my issue is that when I load the screen with data that is supposed to show initially I can populate the dropdown with an AJAX call but the value is not selected I am guessing because it got populated after it was tied to my model.  Is there a way this situation is normally handled?  Below is the code in my document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAll", "Customers")', function (customers) {
        var customerSelect = $('.Customers');
        customerSelect.empty();
        customerSelect.append('<option value="0">Choose Customer...</option>');
        $.each(customers, function (index, customer) {
            customerSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                value: customer.ID,
                text: customer.CustomerName
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

In case this info helps here is the HTML code to load the table

```
<table id="Attendees" class="table-gridview">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:320px">
                    Customer
                </th>
                <th style="width:250px">
                    Attendee
                </th>
                <th>
                    Attended
                </th>
                <th>
                    Paid
                </th>
                <th style="width:120px">
                    Check Number
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Attendees)
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The follwoing code is what is in the editor template for the Attendees

```
<tr class="ClassAttendee">

    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassID)

        @Html.DropDownList("Customers", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @Class = "Customers", style="width:300px" })
    </td>
    <td>    
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.CustomerEmailID,
            Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
            "Choose Attendee...",
                              new { @Class = "Contact", style = "width:220px" }
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEmailID)
    </td>
    <td>    
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Attended)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Attended)
    </td>
    <td>    
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FeePaid, new { @Class = "FeePaid"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FeePaid)
    </td>
    <td>    
        @if (Model.FeePaid != true)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CheckNumber, new { @Class = "CheckNumber", disabled ="true", style = "width:100px" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CheckNumber, new { @Class = "CheckNumber", style = "width:100px" })
        }

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CheckNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Delete, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
        @Html.LinkToRemoveNestedFormUpdateCounter("Remove", "tr.ClassAttendee", "input.mark-for-delete")
    </td>
</tr>
```

The last piece I will show is the server side code for the AJAX call

```
public JsonResult GetAll()
    {
        var customers = customerRepository
            .All
            .Select(p => new
            {
                p.ID ,
                p.CustomerName
            })
            .OrderBy(o => o.CustomerName);
        return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you're getting into the Json in the Controller?

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you are suggesting?  I have not gone through line by line but what I see when the page comes up with a saved line item is the first combo box is populated with values but the one that had been saved it not selected it is sitting on the first value.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you meant you weren't sure if you were getting into your function.  Do you have the saved selected Id hidden in the page?  I wasn't sure if it was the Model Id or ClassId so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: It is the Model.ID shown in the EditorTemplate that si the key for the child items and I do have it hidden for each line in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this to work by not using the editorfor when I am loading the page.  Instead I now populate the table with code below

```
<table id="Attendees" class="table-gridview">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:320px">
                    Customer
                </th>
                <th style="width:250px">
                    Attendee
                </th>
                <th>
                    Attended
                </th>
                <th>
                    Paid
                </th>
                <th style="width:120px">
                    Check Number
                </th>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Attendees)
            {
              <tr class="ClassAttendee">
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ClassID)

                    @Html.DropDownList("Customers", ((IEnumerable<TRIOSoftware.Domain.Entities.Customer>)ViewBag.PossibleCustomers).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.CustomerName),
                       Value = option.ID.ToString(),
                       Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ID == item.CustomerEmail.CustomerID)
                   }),"Choose Customer...", new { @Class = "Customers", style = "width:300px" })
                </td>
                <td> 
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.CustomerEmailID, ((IEnumerable<TRIOSoftware.Domain.Entities.CustomerEmail>)ViewBag.PossibleContacts).Where(o => o.CustomerID == item.CustomerEmail.CustomerID).Select(option => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name),
                        Value = option.ID.ToString(),
                        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ID == item.CustomerEmailID)
                    }), "Choose Attendee...")   
                    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.CustomerEmailID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Choose Attendee...", new { @Class = "Contact", style = "width:220px" })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CustomerEmailID)
                </td>
                <td>    
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Attended)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Attended)
                </td>
                <td>    
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.FeePaid, new { @Class = "FeePaid" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.FeePaid)
                </td>
                <td>    
                    @if (item.FeePaid != true)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.CheckNumber, new { @Class = "CheckNumber", disabled = "true", style = "width:100px" })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.CheckNumber, new { @Class = "CheckNumber", style = "width:100px" })
                    }

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CheckNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Delete, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
                    @Html.LinkToRemoveNestedFormUpdateCounter("Remove", "tr.ClassAttendee", "input.mark-for-delete")
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Basically I moved the template code into the view and instead of populating the drop downs with AJAX I populate the initial ones with data I send into the view.

I will leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone comes up with a better answer as this seems to me to be a brute force solution.

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I had issues with this solution passing values back to the controller to save.  Since I found no other ways to get this to work I added this to the document ready function of the view

```
 $("#Attendees tr").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find("input, select, span").each(function (indx, element) {
            if ($(element).attr('name') !== undefined) {
                var name = $(element).attr('name').replace("item", "Attendees[" + (index - 1) + "]");
                $(element).attr('name', name);
            } else {
                // attribute does not exist
            }

            if ($(element).attr('id') !== undefined) {
                var id = $(element).attr('id').replace("item", "Attendees_" + (index - 1) + "_");
                $(element).attr('id', id);
            } else {
                // attribute does not exist
            }

            if ($(element).attr('data-valmasg-for') !== undefined) {
                var dataval = $(element).attr('data-valmasg-for').replace("item", "Attendees[" + (index - 1) + "]");
                $(element).attr('data-valmasg-for', dataval);
            } else {
                // attribute does not exist
            }
        });


    });
```

Basically I go replace the item ID and Name with the proper name to get my data back to the controller.  It is a bit of a hack but it does work so I wanted to post it.

Comment: Turns out this answer was worse than I thought.  When I used an editor teplate to show my data I got the data put in automaticlaly that allowed my model to get this info back automaticlaly on a post and now using the foreach loop that data got replaces by item which is what I was using in my foreach loop so now when i get bakc to post I have no attendee information.

Comment: With the edit to this answer the solution works.  I like @Michael_B s solution better as it seems like less of a hack but I could not get the data-id for my customer in side my editor tempplate

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but could you do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAll", "Customers")', function (customers) {
        var customerSelect = $('.Customers');
        customerSelect.empty();
        customerSelect.append('<option value="0">Choose Customer...</option>');
        $.each(customers, function (index, customer) {

            var option=$('<option/>', {
                value: customer.ID,
                text: customer.CustomerName
            });
            if(customer.ID=='@(Model.CustomerEmailID)')
                 $(option).attr("selected","selected");

            customerSelect.append(option);

        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you could add the selected id as an attribute of the parent `<td>` like:

```
<td data-id="@(Model.CustomerEmailID)">    
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.CustomerEmailID,
        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
        "Choose Attendee...",
                          new { @Class = "Contact", style = "width:220px" }
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerEmailID)
</td>
```

You could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAll", "Customers")', function (customers) {
        var customerSelect = $('.Customers');
        customerSelect.empty();
        customerSelect.append('<option value="0">Choose Customer...</option>');
        $.each(customers, function (index, customer) {

            var option=$('<option/>', {
                value: customer.ID,
                text: customer.CustomerName
            });
            if(customer.ID==$(this).parent().attr("data-id"))
                 $(option).attr("selected","selected");

            customerSelect.append(option);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My problem with this solution is that I can have any number of lines in my table so it woudl nto be tied to @(Model.CustomerEmailID) it woudl be @(Model.<One of the attendees in my child collection>.CustomerEmailID)

Comment: Still not testing any of this, but I updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Have you looked at this yet, @DaveWade?

Comment: I did try this out but I got an error when tryign to add the data-id on my editor template.Even though I have the CustomerEmail object in my model when I pass it into the view the Editor Template does not receive it so when I try to add data-id of CustomerEmail.CustomerID to one of the dropdowns it fails.

Comment: So the CustomerID is null in the database, or just not being populated in the model?

Comment: its not the CustomerID itself it is the object CustomerEmail that contains the CustomrID that is null when I get to the Editor Template.  The weird thing is that in the view itself I have a CustomerEmail object so I am not sure why it is getting dropped by the Editor Template

Comment: The model I have is ClassAttendee.  This class has the ContactID whic is the ID I need for the second dropdown.  Within ClassAttendee is also CustomerEmail which shodul contian the info that CustomerEmailID is the key for.  In the CustomerEmail object is a CustomerID which is the Data-id I need for the first dropdown.  In my editor template I can populate the data-id for the customeremailID for the second combo but the program crashes sayign it has a null when trying to populate the CustomerID

Comment: Try adding .Include("CustomerEmail") to the Linq query.

Comment: Add it to the controller for the view, not for the GetAll function.  What does your controller for the view look like?